# Compiling program using the this-keyword

Tags: c++, compilation, this, header-files

I am trying to compile a program written by someone else, using makefiles, and I don't have time to learn everything in the program before I use it - therefore I'm mystified by some of the errors.

The first error is

```
(...): In function `_ZN30RealTriDiagonalSymmetricMatrix14ResizeAndCleanEii':
/home/jorgen/diaghamsvn/DiagHam/src/Matrix/RealTriDiagonalSymmetricMatrix.cc:350: 
undefined reference to `GarbageFlag::Used()'
```

The offending line in *RealTriDiagonalSymmetricMatrix.cc* is:

```
if (this->Flag.Used() == true)
```

I look up the file *GarbageFlag.h* and it contains the function *Used()*; here's part of it:

```
class GarbageFlag
{

 private:

#ifdef __SMP__
pthread_mutex_t *FlagMutex;
#endif


public:

// default constructor
GarbageFlag();

// copy constructor
// flag = garbage flag to copy
GarbageFlag(const GarbageFlag& flag);

// destructor
~GarbageFlag();

// return value = reference on current garbage flag
GarbageFlag& operator = (const GarbageFlag& flag);

bool Used ();
```

Also, the file *RealTriDiagonalSymmetricMatrix.cc* includes a header, which again includes *GarbageFlag.h*. So I'm confused as to why it can't find the function.

There are a lot of similar errors after this. Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Comment: Contains, okay... But where is definition of `Used`?

Comment: Either the `Used` function hasn't been implemented, or you're not linking with the object or library that contains the definition. Find the source file that defines it (`GarbageFlag.cc`, perhaps), and make sure the makefile includes that when building your program.

Comment: And you *link* with the object file/library where the `GarbageFlag::Used` function is *defined*?

Comment: @Jorgen it's usually considered bad to alter the question to ask something else.  Your first question was answered, so mark Adrian's post as an answer, and search SO to see about your linker problem.  If you still can't solve it, post a _new_ question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a linker error, so the compiler didn't have a problem with finding the *declaration* of GarbageFlag::Used. What is missing is the *definition* (implementation) of that method.

You need to make sure that the source file which contains the implementation of GarbageFlag::Used is compiled and linked together with the other source files.